# How to add radio button behavior to <a>

Tags: javascript, css, html

I just want to add a radio button behavior(check only one item, change color when is checked, remove checked color when the other is checked.) to 
How can I do this in javascript? Here is my on click event.

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-change-option]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target);
  var optionIndex = parseInt($(this).data('changeOption')), optionValue = $(this).data('changeValue');

  if(optionSelectors.optionExistInSelect(optionSelectors.selectors[optionIndex].element, optionValue)) {
    $(optionSelectors.selectors[optionIndex].element).val(optionValue).trigger('change');
  }
});
```

Comment: what is your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset all items of the type to the base color, than change the clicked one to the active color:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-change-option]', function() {
  $('[data-change-option]').css('color', '');
  
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#1" data-change-option="">Link 1</a>

<a href="#1" data-change-option="">Link 2</a>

<a href="#1" data-change-option="">Link 3</a>
```